# Removing characters before and after a certain string in Python

Tags: python-2.7, base64

I have written a piece of code that uses get request to receive a response from an API in the form of a text file. This file contains a binary encoded in base64 which is of interest to me. I want to be able to extract only this binary from the file using Python so that I can then decode it.

My current code is:

```
    response = requests.get(url, headers=header, verify=False)

    #Decoding response from base64
    decoded_response = base64.b64decode(response)

    #Printing response
    print decoded_response.text

    #Writing response to a file
    f = open("decoded_response.txt","w")
    f = f.read()
    pickle.dump(decoded_response, f)
    f.close()
```

This is throwing a TypeError as expected since the padding before the beginning of the base64 encoded string needs to be removed.
Looking for assistance with this!

[image: Beginning of file]

[image: End of file]

Comment: I know this is not an answer, but an advice, as I don't code in Python (I code in JS, Ruby and Java). I would approach that problem, not removing text, but **extracting** text using a **regular expression** to get only the part I want (which would be the base64 content) and then decode it. However I don't know how big the content is and how that might affect the performance when extracting the content.

Answer (score 0):

The following modified code worked for me:

```
f = open("response.txt","wb")
f.write(json.loads(response.text)['Binary'].decode('base64'))
f.close()
```